# Calendar Webpart not showing correctly

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I created a Calendar, then add it a calendar Webpart that shows it in another page. The problem is that the webpart is not showing it correctly in the Day and Week views. Month view is just fine. It looks that its showing 3 columns.

Here is how it looks in the week view

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the Zone property to "Header" and it work fine.